# Multiple Account association with Contact

Tags: soql, accountcontactrelation

From Summer 16 release, I can associate a single contact to multiple accounts.
However,I am finding it hard to query(SOQL) and get all the related accounts for the contact.
Has anyone done this ?

Thanks for the help!
Regards
Venkat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object you are looking for is the [AccountContactRelation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_accountcontactrelation.htm).

As an example of how to query these relationships:

```
SELECT AccountId, ContactId FROM AccountContactRelation
```

Answer (score -1):

Just found out,
Once you have enabled multi Account in the application, a new junction object called AccountContactRelation is created, we can easily query like below

```
SELECT AccountId,ContactId FROM AccountContactRelation
```